# Is It Possible to Bind Images Using DataGridTextColumn ? If Yes How to do it?

Tags: wpf

I want to Bind **Images** for wpf datagrid Using **DataGridTextColumn**.
I am using Both **DataGridTextColumn** and **DataGridTemplateColumn** in a single Grid.
I am able to display images but Unable to get exact SelectedIndex.

I am placing my code below

```
<DataGrid Name="dgNewBill" Margin="2,0,0,0" BorderThickness="0" HeadersVisibility="None" IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal" Background="White" Cursor="Hand">                                               
                                            <DataGrid.Resources>
                                                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="DarkTurquoise"/>
                                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                                                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkTurquoise" />
                                                            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"></Setter>
                                                            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Medium"></Setter>
                                                        </Trigger>

                                                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                                                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                                                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkTurquoise" />                                                                
                                                            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"></Setter>
                                                            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Medium"></Setter>
                                                        </Trigger>
                                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                                </Style>
                                            </DataGrid.Resources>                                              

                                            <DataGrid.Columns>
                                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="SNumber"  Width="80" Binding="{Binding SNumber }">
                                                    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                                                        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                                            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />  
                                                        </Style>
                                                    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                                                </DataGridTextColumn>
                                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value 1"  Width="100" Binding="{Binding skuId, StringFormat={}{0:C}}">
                                                    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                                                        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                                                            <EventSetter Event="MouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="OpenSelectedItemDetails" />
                                                            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                                        </Style>
                                                    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                                                </DataGridTextColumn>
                                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Width="260" Binding="{Binding description }">
                                                    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                                                        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                                            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
                                                        </Style>
                                                    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                                                </DataGridTextColumn>
                                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Quantity" Width="120" Binding="{Binding quantity }">
                                                    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                                                        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                                                            <EventSetter Event="MouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="OpenSelectedItemQuantity" />
                                                            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                                        </Style>
                                                    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                                                </DataGridTextColumn>
                                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Price" Width="70" Binding="{Binding price, StringFormat={}{0:#.00}}">
                                                    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                                                        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                                            <EventSetter Event="MouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="OpenSelectedItemPriceEdit" />
                                                            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right" />
                                                        </Style>
                                                    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                                                </DataGridTextColumn>
                                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="CartToral" Width="90" Binding="{Binding cartTotal, StringFormat={}{0:#.00}}">
                                                    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                                                        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                                            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right" />
                                                        </Style>
                                                    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                                                </DataGridTextColumn>

                                                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Image" Width="SizeToCells" IsReadOnly="True">
                                                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                                        <DataTemplate>
                                                            <Image Height="20" Source="{Binding Image}" MouseLeftButtonDown="VoidSelectedItem" />
                                                        </DataTemplate>
                                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                                            </DataGrid.Columns>
                                        </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Sooo....and what have you tried so far? And what are the problems you are facing?

Comment: You should be using `DataGridTemplateColumn` instead of `DataGridTextColumn` as it's bound only to text.

Comment: Thank you @user1672994 for your reply. I have tried that also when I am using DataGridTemplateColumn some times I am getting SelectedIndex as -1 can You tell me why this is happening?

Comment: Can you post the code to show where you are getting the error?

Comment: <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                                <Image Height="20" Source="{Binding Image}" MouseLeftButtonDown="VoidSelectedItem" />
                                                            </DataTemplate>
                                                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

Comment: When am using above code in grid getting error as index out of range  in following .cs code   DataGridRow currentRow = this.dgNewBill.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(this.dgNewBill.SelectedIndex) as DataGridRow;

Comment: @user1672994 is it possible to bind data using  DataGridTextColumn and DataGridTemplateColumn in a single datagrid?

Comment: Yes you can add type of DataGridColumn in a data grid.

Comment: When I am using only DataGridTextColumn its working fine but when I am trying to use DataGridTextColumn along with DataGridTemplateColumn Getting selectedIndex as -1 Why its happening ? @user1672994

Comment: Can you give me one example for binding Images using DataGridColumn ? @user1672994

Comment: I am firing some events on grid elements so that first time only grid is selecting thats why I am getting **SelectedIndex** as  **-1** now I am able to solve my issue thank You @user1672994 for your valuable sugestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `DataGridTemplateColumn` instead. Here there is code sample.

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Image" CellTemplate="{StaticResource ImageCellTemplate}"/>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

And define template for it.

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ImageCellTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <Image Source="{Binding Path=Image}"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
<DataGrid.Resources>
```

Comment: Thank you @bars222 for your reply . Now I am able to bind images to DataGrid but When I am firing events  first time I am getting SelectedIndex as -1. Can u please tell me Why this is happening?

Comment: You can try to use DataGrid `SelectionChanged` event. And there get `( DataGrid )sender ).SelectedItem`

Comment: I am firing some events on grid elements so that first time only grid is selecting thats why I am getting **SelectedIndex** as  **-1** now I am able to solve my issue thank You @bars223  for your valuable sugestions.